# Copy file out of docker image during docker build

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a simply Dockerfile to build python requirements into a zip file to be uploaded to AWS Lambda.

```
FROM amazonlinux:2.0.20221004.0

RUN yum install -y python37 && \
    yum install -y python3-pip && \
    yum install -y zip && \
    yum clean all

RUN python3.7 -m pip install --upgrade pip && \
    python3.7 -m pip install virtualenv

COPY aws_requirements.txt .

RUN pip install -r aws_requirements.txt -t ./python
RUN zip -r python.zip ./py
```

Is there a way to copy the python.zip out of the image to the host during the dockerfile?

Comment: Do you also want to create an image? Or is the goal of the build only to create the zip file?

Comment: Goal is to build the zip file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With buildkit, you can output the result to a directory on the host instead of pushing to a registry. So you can put the zip file in a scratch image and then output that:

```
FROM amazonlinux:2.0.20221004.0 as build

RUN yum install -y python37 && \
    yum install -y python3-pip && \
    yum install -y zip && \
    yum clean all

RUN python3.7 -m pip install --upgrade pip && \
    python3.7 -m pip install virtualenv

COPY aws_requirements.txt .

RUN pip install -r aws_requirements.txt -t ./python
RUN zip -r /python.zip ./py

FROM scratch as artifact
COPY --from=build /python.zip /python.zip
```

Then running:

```bash
docker build --output type=local,dest=out .
```

Will create a `out/python.zip` file.